# Can't find any string with IDA, why?

Tags: ida

A friend asked me to make some small mod on a app.
The mod should be to rewrite some labels like button, textbox text into his
language, so he can better understand the app...

I loaded the app to IDA 7.0 and the two dll's too which are UPX packed, but I unpacked it before loading into IDA, but I can't find any string...

Nothing.
There should be some buttons labeled with "Diagnostic", "Settings", "About the program" etc. But no way to figure out why I cant find all the strings...

Here is the link to the files I got:
[Files](https://mega.nz/#!00smnaBL!QjO91FQgeN9ZjRNN8CrzRI3SYqqUwAIDuHgpkqpZDLc)

Any help would be nice.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to search the strings in some other tools? I mean open it with some hex editor and try to search it. BTW, did you try to search in different encodings: UTF8, UTF16?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Yes, I tried in severan hex editors, changed encodings too but nothing.
When I was first edited in my HxD I saw something strange.
It looks for me like if the exe is packed or protected with some software like UPX bit I can't figure out which software is used.
I also checked the exe with PEiD but it says not packed...
Pic.: https://imgur.com/RmthSGd

After opening in IDA I get a warning msg. "The imports segment seems to be destroyed..."
That tells me does something is really buggy.

Comment: The main executable itself is packed with MPRESS.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack MPRESS directly in IDA using the Bochs debugger (or any other supported by IDA). Check [this blog post](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=403) for the details (IDA 6.1 but still mostly applied to current versions).

Disclaimer: I work for Hex-Rays.

Answer (score 0):

The file is compressed with MPRESS. The first thing you do is debug it with OllyDbg. 
You can follow this link for unpacking.

Unpacked size is ~143MB.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Cg6KPMFOG0

I tried to modify the strings.

[image]

[image]

Below, you can see the properties of each strings or button.

[image]

Comment: These strings seems to be in resources section. So if file was loaded to IDA without setting an option to load resources, then it's nothing unexpected, that strings are not found.

Comment: I also set to load the resources but still nothing usable.
As mentioned by the poster before, it is packed with MPRESS, so I have to learn how to extract it...
I never faced MPRESS before...
Is there any simpler way to unpack it?

Comment: Since the file is packed, you cannot find the string you mentioned above even loading it in IDAPro or any disassembler. I think it is the easiest way to unpack the file considering that we already have a tool such as OllyDump and Import Reconstructor.